# Vue3/Capacitor/Ionic ondestroy lifecycle hook?

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, android-lifecycle, capacitor

I'm creating an app using Vue3\Capacitor\Ionic.
One of the tests I've made is to catch the app being shutdown. I just want to send this event to my backend so that it can clean up the db for this session.

Here's a pic from my android simulator:

[image]
When I drag the app up it closes. This is the event I'm trying to catch.

I've tried the Vue3 lifecycle hooks: onUnmounted and OnBeforeUnmount and they don't catch the event. I do see in the logs that Capacitor does catch it:

[image]

So my question is, how do I catch the app closing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hook from Capacitor, see an example below:

```
import { App } from '@capacitor/app';

App.addListener('appStateChange', ({ isActive }) => {
  console.log('App state changed. Is active? ', isActive);
});
```